# PHP Mail method chaining

Tags: php

I am doing an exercise on chaining and the mail method will not display when I chain the methods. Am I missing something here?

```
    <?php

    class User {
       public $firstName;
       public $lastName;

       public function sayHello(){
        echo 'Hello ' . $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
        return $this;
      }

      public function register(){
        echo 'Registered ' . $this->firstName;
        return $this;
      }

      public function mail(){
        return 'Emailed';
      }


    }


    $user1 = new User();
    $user1->firstName = 'John';
    $user1->lastName = 'Doe';
    $user1->sayHello()->register()->mail();


    ?>
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/2iG9p It works.

Answer (score 1):

You are `return`ing the text in `mail()`.

You can either echo it when you call the methods:

```
echo $user1->sayHello()->register()->mail();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6h5pe)

This way will let you save the results to a variable, for instance, to use later:

```
$result = $user1->sayHello()->register()->mail();
// do some work
echo "The result is: ".$result;
```

Or echo it in the method itself:

```
public function mail(){
    echo 'Emailed';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/god1f)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value from the mail method, not echoing it. Try

```
var_dump($user1->sayHello()->register()->mail());
```